# An upper bound whose value is known for the series $ \displaystyle{\sum_{p \text{ prime}}}\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know, series $ \displaystyle{\sum_{p \text{ prime}}}\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}$ is Convergent since it is bounded above by the Convergent series $ \displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.

But can we say anything about where both the series converges or any upper bound whose value is known for the previous series ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear downvoter, kindly mention the reason to downvote.

Comment: (Did not downvote) the latter series sum is [Riemann zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) at $\frac{3}{2}$ (see (9))

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's unclear what you are asking. When you ask "where the series converge," are you asking *what* they converge to? As for an upper bound, would you be satisfied with $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}{1\over p^{3/2}}\lt\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^{3/2}}\lt1+\int_1^\infty{dx\over x^{3/2}}=3$$

Comment: Yeah look I agree with the notion that the identity of actuators of voting events being anon is dumb and pointless or not having a follow up comment enforced as a necessity but I suppose this is something to take up on meta

Comment: Thanks @Barry Cipra, I was asking for such an upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) evaluated at $3/2$.
$$  P(3/2) = 0.849\,562\,683\,621\,566\,446\,3{\dots}  \text{,}  $$
which you can [replicate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BPrimeZetaP%5B3%2F2%5D%2C%2020%5D) yourself.  (You also ask for [$\zeta(3/2) = 2.612375348685488343{\dots}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BZeta%5B3%2F2%5D%2C%2020%5D) and I discuss a method for evaluating $\zeta$ to high precision in [this other Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3389284/123905) on this site.)

Rapid computation of the value of the prime zeta function (implicitly including upper and lower bounds) is described in section 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0900.pdf) by R.J. Mathar.  The sum is broken into the "big part" (terms up to some cutoff), then Moebius inversion (described in the linked Wikipedia article) is used to rewrite the "small part" (terms after the cutoff) as a rapidly converging series.  (This is also described in section 2 of [this paper](http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Ecohen/hardylw.dvi) by Cohen.)

Comment: Thanks for referencing your answer so thoroughly Eric.